# Parsing a string representing a float *with an exponent* in Python

Tags: python

I have a large file with numbers in the form of `6,52353753563E-7`. So there's an exponent in that string. `float()` dies on this.

While I could write custom code to pre-process the string into something `float()` can eat, I'm looking for the pythonic way of converting these into a float (something like a format string passed somewhere). I must say I'm surprised `float()` can't handle strings with such an exponent, this is pretty common stuff.

I'm using python 2.6, but 3.1 is an option if need be.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Nothing to do with exponent. Problem is comma instead of decimal point.

```
>>> float("6,52353753563E-7")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for float(): 6,52353753563E-7
>>> float("6.52353753563E-7")
6.5235375356299998e-07
```

For a general approach, see [locale.atof()](http://docs.python.org/library/locale.html#locale.atof)

Comment: Correct. Incidentally, if you type "6,52353753563E-7" into the Python prompt, it gets parsed as the tuple (6, 5235.3753563) -- fairly obvious why, it just looks odd.

Comment: On a related note, can I somehow make python recognize the comma? C# and Java can do this. Many places in the world use a comma as the decimal separator.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is not in the exponent but in the comma.
with python 3.1:

```
>>> a = "6.52353753563E-7"
>>> float(a)
6.52353753563e-07
```